# Returning rows with comma-separated values by pattern (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

I have some field with comma-separated values:

```
1,2,AA,4,Z
1,ZZ,44,A,1
1,44,33,AA,Z
4,2,Z,A,F
1.2,4,E,1,1
F,1,3.4,3,A
```

Is it possible to select rows with rule: number,number,chars, anything_values?

Result can be:

```
1,2,AA,4,Z
4,2,Z,A,F
1.2,4,E,1,1
```

I'm trying to use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
with s as (
select '1,2,AA,4,Z'   val from dual
union all
select '1,ZZ,44,A,1'  val from dual
union all
select '1,44,33,AA,Z' val from dual
union all
select '4,2,Z,A,F'    val from dual
union all
select '1.2,4,E,1,1'  val from dual
union all
select 'F,1,3.4,3,A'  val from dual
)
select val from s where REGEXP_LIKE(val, '(^|,)[[:digit:]](,|$)');
```

Comment: Could you explain further what your expected output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the CTE.

Would something like this do?

- `INTER` splits every `VAL` into rows
- `LISTAGG` aggregates them back, sorted by numbers and characters

---

```
SQL> with s as (
  2  select '1,2,AA,4,Z'   val from dual
  3  union all
  4  select '1,ZZ,44,A,1'  val from dual
  5  union all
  6  select '1,44,33,AA,Z' val from dual
  7  union all
  8  select '4,2,Z,A,F'    val from dual
  9  union all
 10  select '1.2,4,E,1,1'  val from dual
 11  union all
 12  select 'F,1,3.4,3,A'  val from dual
 13  ),
 14  inter as
 15    (select s.val,
 16            regexp_substr(s.val, '[^,]+', 1, t.column_value) c_one
 17     from s, table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 18                                 connect by level <= regexp_count(s.val, ',') + 1
 19                                ) as sys.odcinumberlist )) t
 20    )
 21  select i.val, listagg(i.c_one, ',') within group
 22                   (order by case when regexp_like(i.c_one, '^\d+|\.|\d+$') then 1
 23                                  when regexp_like(i.c_one, '^[:alpha:]+') then 2
 24                                  else 3
 25                             end) result
 26  from inter i
 27  group by i.val;

VAL          RESULT
------------ --------------------
1,2,AA,4,Z   1,2,4,AA,Z
1,44,33,AA,Z 1,33,44,AA,Z
1,ZZ,44,A,1  1,1,44,A,ZZ
1.2,4,E,1,1  1,1,1.2,4,E
4,2,Z,A,F    2,4,A,F,Z
F,1,3.4,3,A  1,3,3.4,A,F

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer, it rearranges the values rather than selecting only the ones that matches the pattern. And what is the logic for rearranging them, seems to be all numbers first then characters which doesn't fit the pattern.

Comment: Hm, @Joakim, I understand your question. I thought that *source* data have to be rearranged to match the *target* pattern. I might have been wrong, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

This regular expresion should work `'^([0-9.]*,)([0-9.]*,)([A-Z]+)'` if you want to return only the rows that matches the pattern `number, number, word, anything`

```
select val from s where REGEXP_LIKE(val, '^([0-9.]*,)([0-9.]*,)([A-Z]+)');
```